# .P12 Certificate in PHP cURL to an endpoint

Tags: php, curl, ssl-certificate, electronic-signature

I have a .p12 certificate and i want to use it in my call to an endpoint which requires the certificate in order to complete the successful call.

I have added the certificate with Postman and it was a success however when testing locally it is giving me error [ could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?) ]

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        $certFile = '.p12 file path';
        $certPassword = 'certificate Password';  
        curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://prufa.signet.is/SignetService2/v3/api/Signet/GetToken',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
            "username": "username",
            "password": "password",
            "DocID": "",
            "GroupID": "",
            "SSN": "",
            "Onbehalf": "string",
            "Mobile": "",
            "ReturnURL": "https://prufa.signet.is/",
            "UserCert": "string",
            "Manadate": "string"
            }',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ),
            CURLOPT_SSLCERT             => $certFile,
            CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD       => $certPassword
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        if (curl_errno($curl)) {
            $error_msg = curl_error($curl);
            echo $error_msg;
        }
        curl_close($curl);

        echo $response;
```

Comment: So i was able to do it.

Comment: It is a simple fix, Just use the proper CURL headers and it will be good to go